# How to get the list of items from the p tags

Tags: java, xpath, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, cucumber

I am trying to write a test in cucumber jvm which grabs the customers address from the page and assert its is not null.

```
<div class="padder">
<h3>Your details</h3>
<p>
<strong>MR Test Test</strong>
</p>
<p>Selly Road</p>
<p>London</p>
<p>GBR</p>
<p>TR02XZ</p>
</div>
</div>
```

I used xpath to find the first line of the address and the remaining p tags:

```
private static final By CUSTOMER_ADDRESS = By.xpath("//*[@id='yourDetails']/div/p[position() >=2]");
```

This is what I wrote so far but for some reason even though in the xpath I have declared to grab all the p tags after the 2nd p tag my below test does not work:

```
public List<WebElement> returnAllText(By element) {
    List<WebElement> all = driver.findElements(element);
    for (WebElement elements: all) {
       System.out.println(elements.getText());
    }
    return all;
}
```

When the loop runs it finds each line of the address but then it is lost when the return statement is run. How do I catch/store each p tag value and then group it as one string value and assert it is not null

I have debugged the code and the below is the results

When I debug line and evaluate the expression:

```
List<WebElement> all = driver.findElements(element)

result = {java.util.ArrayList@4562} size = 4
[0] = {org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebElement@4564}"[[RemoteWebDriver: chrome on MAC            (32479ef6b2783086b4c1d1ba0bbd1405)] -> xpath: //*[@id='yourDetails']/div/p[position() >=2]]"

[1] = {org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebElement@4565}"[[RemoteWebDriver: chrome on MAC (32479ef6b2783086b4c1d1ba0bbd1405)] -> xpath: //*[@id='yourDetails']/div/p[position() >=2]]"

[2] = {org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebElement@4566}"[[RemoteWebDriver: chrome on MAC (32479ef6b2783086b4c1d1ba0bbd1405)] -> xpath: //*[@id='yourDetails']/div/p[position() >=2]]"

[3] = {org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebElement@4567}"[[RemoteWebDriver: chrome on MAC (32479ef6b2783086b4c1d1ba0bbd1405)] -> xpath: //*[@id='yourDetails']/div/p[position() >=2]]"
```

Then I evaluate:

```
for(WebElement elements: all)

result = {java.util.ArrayList@4276} size = 4
[0] = {org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebElement@4288}"[[RemoteWebDriver: chrome on MAC (32479ef6b2783086b4c1d1ba0bbd1405)] -> xpath: //*[@id='yourDetails']/div/p[position() >=2]]"

[1] = {org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebElement@4289}"[[RemoteWebDriver: chrome on MAC (32479ef6b2783086b4c1d1ba0bbd1405)] -> xpath: //*[@id='yourDetails']/div/p[position() >=2]]"

[2] = {org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebElement@4290}"[[RemoteWebDriver: chrome on MAC (32479ef6b2783086b4c1d1ba0bbd1405)] -> xpath: //*[@id='yourDetails']/div/p[position() >=2]]"

[3] = {org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebElement@4291}"[[RemoteWebDriver: chrome on MAC (32479ef6b2783086b4c1d1ba0bbd1405)] -> xpath: //*[@id='yourDetails']/div/p[position() >=2]]"
```

Then I evaluate:

```
System.out.println(elements.getText())

result = {java.lang.String@4598}"London"
value = {char[9]@4599}
hash = 0
hash32 = 0
```

Evaluate:

```
return all;

result = {java.util.ArrayList@4276} size = 4
[0] = {org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebElement@4288}"[[RemoteWebDriver: chrome on MAC (32479ef6b2783086b4c1d1ba0bbd1405)] -> xpath: //*[@id='yourDetails']/div/p[position() >=2]]"

[1] = {org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebElement@4289}"[[RemoteWebDriver: chrome on MAC (32479ef6b2783086b4c1d1ba0bbd1405)] -> xpath: //*[@id='yourDetails']/div/p[position() >=2]]"

[2] = {org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebElement@4290}"[[RemoteWebDriver: chrome on MAC (32479ef6b2783086b4c1d1ba0bbd1405)] -> xpath: //*[@id='yourDetails']/div/p[position() >=2]]"

[3] = {org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebElement@4291}"[[RemoteWebDriver: chrome on MAC (32479ef6b2783086b4c1d1ba0bbd1405)] -> xpath: //*[@id='yourDetails']/div/p[position() >=2]]"
```

Comment: If the loop prints each `<p>` value, then they are all in the `all` list. What do you mean by "is lost"?

Comment: When I debug the for loop it finds each p tag but then when return all is executed only the first p tag found is returned. I want the method to grab all of the address lines

Comment: This is impossible. The return statement returns a reference to list `all`, and if you print this list in the loop, then it does contain whatever is printed, one element per line. And these elements must be in the list, whose reference is returned. -- Please add whatever is printed by the loop to your question.

Comment: Hi @laune I have updated my original post above with the debug results. Please take a look.

Comment: The evaluation of `System.out.println(elements.getText())` as you have added it just shows the value of the second `<p>`, but you wrote in an earlier comment "the for loop it finds each p tag". Did you really see "Selly Road", "GBR", "TR02XZ"? Also: what does the debugger show *after return from returnAllText*?

Comment: Sorry it always shows the second p tag. In my original question above I have put the debug results for return all;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to resolve the issue. For some reason using the xpath to retrieve all the p tags was not working so instead I used the div id that was one level higher up (parent of the div class=padder):

```
 private static final String CUSTOMER_DETAILS = "yourDetails";
```

this allowed me to retrieve all the elements containing text until the closing div

```
<h3>Your details</h3>
<p>
<strong>MR Test Test</strong>
</p>
<p>Selly Road</p>
<p>London</p>
<p>GBR</p>
<p>TR02XZ</p>
```

then I used this method to construct the address:

```
// return all text in a list and build into a string
public String returnAddress(By element) {
    String[] addressSplit = driver.findElement(element).getText().split("\n");
    StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();
    for (int addressLength = 2; addressLength <= addressSplit.length - 1; addressLength++) {
        str.append(addressSplit[addressLength] + "\n");
    }
    return str.toString().trim();
}


// this calls the method above
public String customerAddressIsPresent() {
    return returnAddress(By.id(CUSTOMER_DETAILS));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your debug results (only "London") and your statement in the question ("the loop [...] finds each line") contradict each other. I suggest that you rewrite your method like this:

```
public String returnAllText(By element) {
    List<WebElement> all = driver.findElements(element);
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    int i = 1;
    for (WebElement element: all) {
        sb.append( i++ ).append( ": " ).append( element.getText() );
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

And let's see what this produces *after the return from the method*. -- The numbering (i) can be removed later, and a line feed might be added, depending on how you want the composed lines.